# Why ReplaySubject returns all values?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular8

I have service:

```
private publishSubscribeSubject_: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject();
private emiter_: Observable<any>;

public publish(channel: EventsChannels, event: any) {
   this.publishSubscribeSubject_.next({ channel: channel, event: event });
}

public subscribe(channel: EventsChannels[] | EventsChannels , handler: (value: any) => void) {
   return this.emiter_
      .filter(emission => emission.channel === channel)
      .map(emission => emission.event)
      .subscribe(handler);
}
```

Using is in component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.objectDetailsSubscription = this.eventService.subscribe(
      EventsChannels.OBJECT_DETAILS,
      semantic => {
        console.log(semantic);
      }
    );
  }
```

Why each time when I activate component I see all last values in `ngOnInit() {}` from `ReplaySubject`?

```
<app-object-details *ngIf="menuItemType === menuItemTypes.ObjectDetails"></app-object-details>
```

Comment: Because you haven't specified how many replays there should be.

Comment: Should I set it like: new ReplaySubject(1);

Comment: You should use BehaviorSubject if you need only current value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify how many "replays" there should be by doing:

```
new ReplaySubject(2) // Will replay last 2 values
```

You will always get all values.

Check out this link to learn more:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject